# django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter

Tags: django, django-orm

There is a model:

```
class UserToOrgunit(models.Model):
    store_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    role = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

`role` can be `SD`, `DSD`, `AMD`. Each `role` has priority: `SD` has the highest priority and `ADM` the lowest.

For each `store_id` I need to receive `UserToOrgunit` instance with the highest `role`.

Sample data:

```
store_id | role
----------------
1        | SD
1        | ADM
2        | DSD
3        | DSD
3        | SD
```

Expected output:

```
store_id | role
----------------
1        | SD
2        | DSD
3        | SD
```

I tried this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, Window, F, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber

priority = Case(
    When(role='SD', then=Value(0)),
    When(role='DSD', then=Value(1)),
    When(role='ADM', then=Value(2)),
    output_field=IntegerField()
)

row_number = Window(
    expression=RowNumber(),
    partition_by=[F('store_id')],
    order_by=F('priority').asc()
)

UserToOrgunit.objects.annotate(priority=priority, row_number=row_number).filter(row_number=1)
```

But there is error with this:

> django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter
> clause.

How to deal with this? Or mayby it can be handle without `RowNumber`? If so how? Beside rawsql.

P.S. It seems if without Window I need to annotate another column like `highest_priority`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a raw query like this:

```
query = """
      SELECT id, store_id, role, CASE WHEN role = 'SD' THEN 3 
      WHEN role = 'DSD' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END p FROM your_app_usertoorgunit
      GROUP BY store_id HAVING MAX(p);
"""
objs = UserToOrgunit.objects.raw(query)
for obj in objs:
  # do something with obj
```